# How to remove empty space between <ul>s, with list-group-horizontal (boostrap 4)?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a small project for school.
I'm printing results from a database, and I put the data into 3 different 'list-group-item', and every row of data is in a different .
So, it's an ul for every row (and I have to print a lot of them).
The problem is the space between every , and I'm really getting crazy.

I tried everything found on the internet, but really can't resolve my problem.

[image: This is how it looks like now]
I'd like that the spaces between the different rows to totally disappear.
Thanks to anyone :)

```css
.list-group-horizontal {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
  display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left:-4px;
    margin-right: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    width: 33%;
    height: 55px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">Nome Libro</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Data Prestito</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Data Riconsegna</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">I Robot</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">2018-01-19 03:14:07</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">2019-01-19 03:14:07</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could add a style for `ul` and remove the margin/padding that's added. But I think a better approach would be to have a more table like layout using something like CSS Grids

Answer (score -1):

```css
.list-group-horizontal {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
  display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left:-4px;
    margin-right: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
    width: 33%;
    height: 55px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #d00;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">Nome Libro</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Data Prestito</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Data Riconsegna</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-group-horizontal">
  <li class="list-group-item">Nome Libro</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Data Prestito</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Data Riconsegna</li>
</ul>
```